# LINQ to Entities does not recognize my method

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, linq-method-syntax

I want to convert date and time to Persian in LINQ select but linq can not recognize my method :

> *LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String toPersianDateTime(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

How can I change my method to LINQ compatible?

My method :

```
public static string toPersianDateTime(DateTime dt)
{
    PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
    string pDateTime = pc.GetYear(dt).ToString() + "/" + pc.GetMonth(dt).ToString() + "/" + pc.GetDayOfMonth(dt).ToString() + " ";
    pDateTime += pc.GetHour(dt) + ":" + pc.GetMinute(dt) + ":" + pc.GetSecond(dt);
    return pDateTime;
}
```

And my LINQ code :

```
var result = (from ord in db.vw_orders
              where ord.uid == user.id
              orderby ord.order_date descending
              select new { ord.id,
                           date = Tools.toPersianDateTime((DateTime)ord.order_date),
                           ord.is_final, 
                           ord.status, 
                           ord.image_count, 
                           ord.order_count, 
                           ord.total_price });
```

Comment: I would also look at simplifying `toPersianDateTime`.  Seems like it could be replaced with a single call to `DateTime.ToString()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EF cannot translate your custom method to SQL.  You can inject a `.AsEnumerable()` call to change the underlying context from EF to Linq-to-Objects:

```
var result = (from ord in db.vw_orders
              where ord.uid == user.id
              orderby ord.order_date descending select ord
             )
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Select(o => new { o.id,
                                date = Tools.toPersianDateTime((DateTime)o.order_date),
                                o.is_final, 
                                o.status, 
                                o.image_count, 
                                o.order_count, 
                                o.total_price }
                    );
```

Comment: Thank you Stanley, It's exactly what I want.